# Extrapolating an abstract algebra proof, arriving upon an incorrect conclusion.

Tags: field-theory

Could you kindly point out what is wrong with my reasoning?

**EDIT: What I have unintendedly proven through my reasoning is that every field can only have one automorphism- the identity mapping. Hope this helps in navigating the mess below**

Let $k_{1},k_{2},\dots k_{n}$ be an arbitrary number of **distinct, non-zero** elements $\in\mathbb{K}$. $\mathbb{K}$ is a field of $0$ characteristic.

Also, $\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2},\dots \sigma_{m}$ are **distinct** automorphisms of $\mathbb{K}$.

I will show that $m\leq n$.

Let us assume that $m>n$. We can form the following system of linear equations:

$$\sigma_{1}(k_{1})x_{1}+\sigma_{2}(k_{1})x_{2}+\dots \sigma_{m}(k_{1})x_{m}=0$$ $$\sigma_{1}(k_{2})x_{1}+\sigma_{2}(k_{2})x_{2}+\dots \sigma_{m}(k_{2})x_{m}=0$$ $$\dots$$$$\dots$$$$\sigma_{1}(k_{n})x_{1}+\sigma_{2}(k_{n})x_{2}+\dots \sigma_{m}(k_{n})x_{m}=0$$

As $m>n$, we are assured a non-zero solution for $(x_{1},x_{2},\dots x_{m})$. Let it be $(a_{1}, a_{2},\dots a_{m})$, not all zero.

Then, taking the first linear equation into consideration, $$\sigma_{1}(k_{1})a_{1}+\sigma_{2}(k_{1})a_{2}+\dots \sigma_{m}(k_{1})a_{m}=0, a_{i}\in\mathbb{K}$$

This is not possible (I can give a proof, but it would unnecessarily lengthen the discussion).

*Hence, on selecting an arbitrary ($n$) number of elements from $\mathbb{K}$, this result shows that the number of automorphisms $\mathbb{K}$ can have $\leq n$. This directly implies that the number of automorphisms $\mathbb{K}$ has is $1$*- the identity automorphism.

It is quite obvious that this conclusion is wrong. What is erroneous in my thought process though?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to prove, though it looks something connected to fields extension and its automorphisms... **yet** : how is it possible that $\,m,n\,$ are related, just like that? What you wrote is that no matter how many *different* non-zero elements you choose in the field, there are *always* less than that number *distinct* automorphisms. This cannot possibly be right and I think you may misunderstanding something somewhere...

Comment: @DonAntonio- 1. My assertion is the number of distinct automorphisms=$1$. 2. This proof is an extrapolation of the proof given in Herstein as part of Theorem $5.R$, which proves the number of automorphisms of field extension $\mathbb{K}\leq [\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{F}]$.

Comment: I've mentioned the conclusion of my erroneous reasoning right at the beginning. Hope that helps. Thanks :)

Comment: Again, @Ayush : it's not an extrapolation of that theorem in Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", but a rather bizarre...wording of a completely nonsensical fact: you're saying that if you have **one** nonzero element in the field $\,K\,$, then the number of *different* automorphism of $\,K\,$ is zero or one...does this sound even remotely true to you?!

Comment: @DonAntonio- I know that my conclusion is wrong, as I've stated multiple times in my post. It would just be great if someone could point out where my reasoning goes haywire...please note that the fact that I am wrong somehwere is not denied by me, but openly accepted. In fact, it forms the very basis for this question.

Comment: @DonAntonio- Also, it's an extrapolation because: where I have taken $k_{1},k_{2}\dots$, Herstein has taken the base elements of $\mathbb{[K:F]}$. With my limited understanding, I could not figure out why I could not take any number of elements of $\mathbb{K}$, and arrive upon the same result. Hence the question :). Thanks

Comment: You might inadvertently be assuming that $\mathbb K$ is the fixed field of all your automorphisms - in which case the indentity is the only possibility. This kind of argument is more usually deployed to consider automorphisms of an extension, where the ground field is fixed.

Comment: Well Ayush, then let us try this: do you know that in general the field $\,K\,$ has *more* than one automorphism? If you know this then reading my past comment shows at once that your claim is wrong.

Comment: Ayush, is *not* an extrapolation because Herstein took a **finite** extension $\,K/F\,$ and then he talks about automorphism of $\,K\,$ *leaving* $\,F\,$ fixed ...! Not even close, imo, to an extrapolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake must lie in the assertion that

$$\sigma_1(k_1)a_1 + \cdots +\sigma_m(k_1)a_m = 0$$

is impossible.

---

Namely, if we let $k_1 = 1$, it is trivial to see that there will be $a_1\ldots a_m$ making this true: just let $a_m = -(a_1+\cdots + a_{m-1})$. This is in direct contradiction with your observation.

Without your purported proof of the above statement, not much more can be said.

Comment: You are right. This exact assertion is wrong, and thanks for leading me to a deeper understanding. What is although true is $\sigma_{1}(u)a_{1}+\sigma_{2}(u)a_{2}+\dots \sigma_{m}(u)a_{m}\neq 0$, for ALL $u\in\mathbb{K}$. Hence, although the statement may be true for some $u_{i}\in\mathbb{K}$, given a set of automorphisms $\sigma_{i}$, $a_{i}\in\mathbb{K}$ can't always be found such that the expression is satisfied for **every** $u\in\mathbb{K}$. That is where Herstein's proof kicks in- which takes only base elements into consideration, rather than any $k_{1},k_{2},\dots\in\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Every element of $\mathbb{K}$ can be constructed from the elements of $[\mathbb{K:F}]$. Hence, we can take every $u\in\mathbb{F}$ into consideration now. We reach a contradiction. This proves the number of automorphisms of $\mathbb{K}$ which fix $\mathbb{F}$ are $\leq$ $[\mathbb{K:F}]$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me from the comments that you have based your proof a situation in which $\mathbb K$ is an extension of the ground field $\mathbb F$, and the author is examining the automorphisms of $\mathbb K$ which fix $\mathbb F$ in order to get make a comparison with the degree of the extension.

If you have, then your proof essentially assumes $\mathbb F = \mathbb K$, the degree of the extension is $1$, and the automorphisms you are considering are assumed to fix $\mathbb K$. The only automorphism of $\mathbb K$ which fixes $\mathbb K$ is the identity, and what you have done is to prove a special case of the general theorem.

You have not given enough information to show where the assumption about the fixed field comes in - it would be in the part of the proof that you haven't given.

Comment: @MarkBennet- Yes, I have based my proof on automorphisms of $\mathbb{K}$ that fix $\mathbb{F}$. $F$ is the fixed field of teh automorphisms here. My whole proof was hinged on a statement I hadn't fully comprehended, as I've mentioned in my comments accompanying Lord_Farin's answer. Thanks :)